# Socket io in nest js not receiving acknowledgements

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a little problem with acknowledgements function in socket io using `nestjs` framework.

Normally, with the code below, the `data` parameter in the `onStartSearch` function should contain the data and `ack` function to notify the frontend with. But the data params contain only data sent from the frontend.

**Backend**

```
@SubscribeMessage('startSearch')
  async onStartSearch(socket, data) {


    logger.info('User ' + socket.id + ' startedSearch');
    logger.debug(data);

    if (Joi.validate(data, requestSchema).error) {
      return ack({
        status: 'error',
        reason: 'invalid params format',
      });
    }
```

**Frontend**

```
  public sendMessage(payload: IChatMessage) {
        this.socket.emit('message', payload, function(test) {
            console.log("acckk received")
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just return plain data, the acknowledgment (callback) function will automatically be called by nest:

```
@SubscribeMessage('startSearch')
async onStartSearch(socket, data) {
  if (Joi.validate(data, requestSchema).error) {
      return {
        status: 'error',
        reason: 'invalid params format',
      };
    }
}
```

---

But you can also work without the callback function (e.g. when working with native sockets which don't support the callback function):

The `@SubsribeMessage` methods can also return an `Observable<WsResponse<any>>`. `WsResponse` contains the event name and the payload `{event: string, data: any}`.

```
@SubscribeMessage('startSearch')
async onStartSearch(socket, data): Observable<WsResponse<any>> {
  if (Joi.validate(data, requestSchema).error)
    return of({event: 'searchResponse', data});
  }
```

Then just listen to the response on your client:

```
socket.on('searchResponse', function (data) {
  console.log('event', data);
});
```